# Keep files architecture while moving it

Tags: bash, find, mv

I would like to move some files from one folder to another. Say I have:

```
├── bar
│   ├── a_folder
│   │   └── apicture.png
│   └── another_folder
│       └── myfile.txt
└── foo
```

And I would like to have every txt files moved from `bar` to `foo`:

```
├── bar
│   ├── a_folder
    │   └── apicture.png
│   └── another_folder
└── foo
    └── another_folder
        └── myfile.txt
```

I tried using `find` command using:

```
find bar -type f -exec mv {} $temp/{} \;
```

This should work but only if folders are already existing in `foo` folder. Thus I am looking for a way to create these folders in `foo`, and it seems that `mv` does not do that. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

```
cp -R bar/. foo/
find bar -type f -delete
```

Yes that involves a copy and isn't a one-liner, but unless we're talking huge amounts of data and a recurring job here, it's a good stop-gap. (Note the `bar/.` instead of the usual `bar/*`, as the latter would miss dot-files.)

I doubt there is a one-liner way to *move* the files but *keep* the directories anyway.

Comment: I edited my question because actually I do not want to move every files, only some of them. I guess your solution (+ 1 more line) would still work though?

Comment: @Cqnqrd: Actually your edit changed the question fundamentally. You could still get this done with a somewhat-complex `find`, but that's beyond the 30-second window I allow myself for SO answers. Sorry. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[`rsync`](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) has this capability built in.

```
cd bar && rsync --relative [--no-implied-dirs] . ../foo/
```

Use --no-implied-dirs if there are symlinks in the tree you want to keep as symlinks.

If you only want to move files where the destination directory already exists, use the `--no-dirs` flag.

rsync is not in the POSIX toolset, but it is common on UNIX-like machines including OS X and most Linuxen.